# 100% height is not appling to body background image on mobile view

Tags: html, css

I have added a bg image to body.. on mobile view it does not show fit the full height of mobile.. a tried it then giving bg-attachment : fixed but that also doesn't work.

I tried it with bg-attachment fixed.. giving height 100%

```
    body{
    background: url(../images/body-bg.jpg?v=1.1) no-repeat center top fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    height : 100%}
```

the bg height is only visible till the content we have used

Comment: height:100% to html also

Comment: Use 100vh to make it the height of your screen, not the content, or use min-height: to set a minimum height

Comment: Yes thanks height 100vh works